# document.querySelector reading only 1 class

Tags: javascript, php, html

The `document.getElementById` is executing only the first `<ul>` when I click, I want all the `ul`'s working as I click inside them.

PHP

```
for ($i=0; $i < $Count_Assoc['dev'] ; $i++) { 

  $History_Assoc = mysqli_fetch_array($HistoryQuery);

  echo '<ul class="repoFolder" data-value="'. $History_Assoc['devaddr'] .'">';
  echo '<br>';

  echo '<h5 style=" color: black;
  padding: 0px 9em 0em 0em;">DevAddr:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspData:</h5>';
  echo '<p>'.$History_Assoc['devaddr'].'&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp'.$History_Assoc['data'].'</p>';

  echo "</ul>";
  echo '<br>';

}
```

Javascript

```
document.querySelector('.repoFolder').onclick = function() {rootFolder()};

function rootFolder() {
  alert(document.querySelector('.repoFolder').getAttribute('data-value'));
}
```

Comment: id's must be unique. You should look into using classes instead

Comment: chevybow I tried with classes as well and the same error appeard I tried using document.querySelector('.repofolder').onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the class on your lists, rather than the Id. Id is supposed to be a unique identifier, but class is a way to can create multiple common elements. Here I have changed your ids into classes

```
for ($i=0; $i < $Count_Assoc['dev'] ; $i++) { 

  $History_Assoc = mysqli_fetch_array($HistoryQuery);

  echo '<ul class="repoFolder" data-value="'. $History_Assoc['devaddr'] .'">';
  echo '<br>';

  echo '<h5 style=" color: black;
  padding: 0px 9em 0em 0em;">DevAddr:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspData:</h5>';
  echo '<p>'.$History_Assoc['devaddr'].'&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp'.$History_Assoc['data'].'</p>';

  echo "</ul>";
  echo '<br>';

}
```

And JavaScript:

```
var folders = document.getElementsByClassName("repoFolder");
for (let i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
  folders[i].onclick = function() {rootFolder.call(this)}; // note that I am passing in the context to rootFolder. 
}

function rootFolder() {

  alert(this.getAttribute('data-value'));

}
```

Comment: @VictorZaccagnini sorry the first line of the javascript `.getElementByClass` was incorrect and not a function. I have corrected it. Try again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to select all element with a class `repoFolter` and loop through each element and append the eventListener

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.repoFolder');
elements.forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', rootFolder);
})

function rootFolder( ){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

From [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com)

> The querySelector() method returns the first element that matches a
>   specified CSS selector(s) in the document.

If you want to get all the elements with specific class or name:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("text").onclick = function () {
    alert("Called");
}
```